# Can I output key/value pairs such that one key is specific to one node in Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Suppose I have a code for matrix multiplication. I want it such that the mapper output from each node would be taken by one reducer, ie. the key for one complete mapper output file will be same, which will be different from key of another node. eg. if one Mapper file outputs key/value pairs with key 1, then another Mapper will output key/value pairs as key 2 and so on. 
I understand that maybe this cannot be done for this example, but if I could output the key as some particular datanode ID or something? As in, the key in the output could be some partciluar ID for a given datanode. Is there a way to do this?

Basically I want all output from one mapper to go into one reducer somehow, and that can be achieved by giving them all **one key**, and I also want some parallelism so that the mapper output is distributed through the cluster, so I want the key for each to be unique. 
How to assign this **one key** to certain data if the input is not organized like that?

(Please point out if additional information is needed. Thank you for your help)

Comment: you can design your own custom partitioner and ensure that the right keys are going to the right reducer. Check out some examples on secondary sort using mapreduce to know how a custom partitioner works.

Comment: The problem is how to generate those keys. One key for one mapper, another key for another dependent on the node where the mapper output is at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure that all output from one mapper ends up in the same reduce instance, uou can use the map task id as your output key:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
    private IntWritable mapId;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        mapId = new IntWritable(context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID().getId());
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // ...

        context.write(mapId, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is very close to what I wanted! Thanks a lot!